# Statistics module doesn't update when getting a node

Tags: nodes

I've created a custom module, which should regarding some other posts help updating the daycount. But it just doesn't get updated.

```
function services_statistics_improved_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
      // Increment hit count for node view api requests.
      if($controller['callback'] == '_node_resource_retrieve') {
        $nid = $result->nid; // May need to confirm this is the node id.
        dpm($controller);
        // See statistics_exit()
        if (variable_get('statistics_count_content_views', 0)) {
          // A node has been requested, so update the node's counters.
          db_merge('node_counter')->key(array('nid' => $nid))->fields(array(
            'daycount' => 1,
            'totalcount' => 1,
            'weekcount' => 1,
            'monthcount' => 1,
            'yearcount' => 1,
            'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
          ))
          ->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')
          ->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')
          ->expression('weekcount', 'weekcount + 1')
          ->expression('monthcount', 'monthcount + 1')
          ->expression('yearcount', 'yearcount + 1')
          ->execute();
        }
      }
    }
```

Anyone able to help me out here?

Comment: Are you sure `$result->nid` contains the node id, it might be an array instead. Also, double check you have statistics enabled in admin > system > statistics. Lastly, ensure your module is enabled and clear caches to make sure your new module hook is registered, if needed.

Comment: Yes the dpm($result) returns the object with ->nid inside. All the other things is checked and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query to update the node_counter table may need tuning.

e.g:

```
if (variable_get('statistics_count_content_views', 0)) {
  // A node has been served, so update the node counters.
  db_merge('node_counter')
    ->key(array('nid' => $nid))
    ->fields(array(
      'daycount' => 1,
      'totalcount' => 1,
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')
    ->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')
    ->execute();
}
```

The other fields, such as 'yearcount' etc.. aren't in the node_counter, at least not by default which may be causing a PDOException there.

Comment: I think i might have figured out why, I'm currently using the [Services Entity Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity), when i use the standard resource provided by the service module, it actually counts up - How come the Services Entity Module doesn't reflect the count up?

In regard to your answer, I've installed the Statitics extra module which gives the extra types of count types.

Comment: Ah ok, if it's a different module, you'll need to update the controller callback to match the other API resource

Comment: Hi again, David Thomas.
I got it working, all tho it doesn't count anonymous hits on the request if i turn on anonymous cache in the performance tab. Any suggetions?

Comment: @Andreas'aNdy'Berggreen if the services response is cached, then the db stats update won't happen for the cached response because hook_services_request_postprocess_alter won't be called.

Comment: Okay, is there a workaround for this, or in any way you could add increment to the counter when a node is pulled through services?

Comment: David can you help me out?